# How to encrypt a video for local playback

Tags: video

I need to encrypt some video files for real time local playback. My objective is to protect the files, even a user copies the files but he is unable to play them.

I have considered some DRM solutions, but most of them need to connect to the Internet for verifying the license.

Since the computer for playing video is a standalone PC and does not connect to the Internet, DRM solutions seem not applicable in my situation.

Does anyone have some good idea about how to do this task?

Thanks.